# WiringPi can only turn on 8 LEDs

Tags: pi-3, gpio, led, php, wiringpi

On my RPi 3 I have a PHP website to control 10 LEDs. Each is wired to a separate GPIO pin and 220 ohm resistor.

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>LED Control</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input[type=submit] {
            width: 20em;  height: 20em;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="1 ON" name="led1on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="1 OFF" name="led1off">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="2 ON" name="led2on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="2 OFF" name="led2off">
                </form>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="3 ON" name="led3on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="3 OFF" name="led3off">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="4 ON" name="led4on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="4 OFF" name="led4off">
                </form>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="5 ON" name="led5on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="5 OFF" name="led5off">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="6 ON" name="led6on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="6 OFF" name="led6off">
                </form>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="7 ON" name="led7on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="7 OFF" name="led7off">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="8 ON" name="led8on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="8 OFF" name="led8off">
                </form>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="9 ON" name="led9on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="9 OFF" name="led9off">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="10 ON" name="led10on">
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                <input type="submit" value="10 OFF" name="led10off">
                </form>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php
$setmode21 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 21 out");
if(isset($_GET['led1on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 21 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led1off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 21 0");
}

$setmode20 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 20 out");
if(isset($_GET['led2on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 20 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led2off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 20 0");
}

$setmode26 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 26 out");
if(isset($_GET['led3on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 26 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led3off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 26 0");
}

$setmode16 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 16 out");
if(isset($_GET['led4on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 16 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led4off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 16 0");
}

$setmode19 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 19 out");
if(isset($_GET['led5on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 19 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led5off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 19 0");
}

$setmode13 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 13 out");
if(isset($_GET['led6on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 13 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led6off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 13 0");
}

$setmode12 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 12 out");
if(isset($_GET['led7on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 12 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led7off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 12 0");
}

$setmode6 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 6 out");
if(isset($_GET['led8on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 6 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led8off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 6 0");

$setmode3 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 3 out");
if(isset($_GET['led9on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 3 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led9off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 3 0");
}

$setmode2 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 2 out");
if(isset($_GET['led10on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 2 1");
}
else if(isset($_GET['led10off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 2 0");
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And the wiring is here:
[image: wiring]

The problem is that LEDs 9 and 10 do not light up. I have tried switching output pins of LEDs 9 and 10, which didn't fix anything. I swapped the wires for 7 and 8 with 9 and 10, which made LEDs 9 and 10 (connected to 7 and 8) turn on and LEDs 7 and 8 not turning on.

If I go to python and set all 10 pins to `HIGH` all the LEDs turn on as expected.

When I turn on the Pi LEDs 9 and 10 are dim, but on.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: We need to see the code you are using and a photo of your connections.

Comment: I'm ditching this code and restarting with python; feel free to answer though.